# How to run a batch file in parallel with MATLAB?

Tags: batch-file, matlab, simulink

I am developing a Simulink Toolbox for an external program, the issue is that I need to run both programs in parallel. I could run the external program calling a batch file from MATLAB, but the program is designed to wait for information given by Simulink in each step of simulation. The program retrieves the information, process it and send a report to Simulink to run another step of the simulation (The process is done iteratively). If I run the batch file from Simulink, then it can not execute the actions of other blocks because it waits until the end of the program performance.

Any ideas of how to solve it?

Comment: could you please show us a kind of "flow chart" how your coupled simulation is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you want. The obvious is to start both programs.

If your language is like most others you can shell to cmd and return without waiting.

```
cmd /c start "Window Title" "c:\some folder\some file.bat"
```

But you can just start both programs at a command prompt or batch file (as two lines is fine - lose the ampersand). The format I'm using to start matlab looks up matlab path in the registry's apppaths key if its not in the current folder.

```
start matlab&start "" "c:\some folder\some file.bat"
```

If you use quotes anywhere in Start you MUST put in WindowTitle. I've put a blank one in above line for the batch. And because I'm looking matlab up in registry I don't need quotes so I didn't bother specifing a windows title.

You can also type in a command prompt without using start. If matlab is a GUI program (a program that does not open a console window) then typing it in a command prompt starts it and returns (but not in a batch file). Also have to tell windows where it is.

```
"c:\some matlab folder\matlab"
"c:\some folder\some file.bat"
```

How are the program's communicating?